# Can I use the {ext:freeform:composer} tag inside a richtext field?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I would like to be able to add a form within a rich text field (or wygwam) but it just renders the tag as a string instead of pre-processing it. Is there a way around this? (parse="inward" doesn't work.)

any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use something like the [Allow EE Code](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code) plugin if you want to parse EE tags like that.

Having said that FreeForm has a fieldtype already built into the Pro version that allows you to select one of your available forms and insert it in the page. This is probably the ideal approach so your editors don't have to worry about proper EE syntax.